# How to add a new column to this bigquery/sql query using a subquery or other method

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

I've created this query:

```
SELECT
  country,
  place,
  label_date,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat1' THEN Value
    ELSE
    0
  END
    ) AS t_s,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat2' THEN Value
    ELSE
    0
  END
    ) AS non_ps,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat3' THEN Value
    ELSE
    0
  END
    ) AS f_h,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat4' THEN Value
    ELSE
    0
  END) AS f_s,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat5' THEN Value
    ELSE
    0
  END) AS o_hp,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat6' THEN Value
    ELSE
    0
  END) AS o_hps,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat7' THEN Value
    ELSE
    0
  END) AS a_s,
  SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat8' THEN Value
    ELSE
    0
  END) AS u_s
FROM
  `my_database`
where country is not null group by country, place, label_date order by country desc
```

I used aggregations because I need to avoid having nulls and zeroes.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80pbp.png) and not [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ4UU.png).

Now I have this other query:

```
 select country, place, label_date, if((sum(value)/count(Value))=0,1,sum(value)/count(Value)) as s_u from `my_database` where Category = 'cat9' group by country, place, label_date
```

and I want to add it but I can't.

I've tried doing this join:

```
FROM
  `my_database` as main
JOIN(select country, place, label_date, if((sum(value)/count(Value))=0,1,sum(value)/count(Value)) as s_u from `my_database` where Category = 'cat9' group by country, place, label_date) as s_u ON main.country = s_u.country
where country is not null group by country, place, label_date order by country desc
```

I used country since sadly I don't have a unique id, but I get the error country is redundant.

I also tried this:

```
SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat8' THEN Value
    ELSE
    0
  END) AS u_s,
SUM(CASE
      WHEN Category = 'cat9' THEN if((sum(value)/count(Value))=0,1,sum(value)/count(Value))
    ELSE
    0
  END) AS u_s
FROM
  `my_database`
where country is not null group by country, place, label_date order by country desc
```

but now I get a can aggregate aggregations error.

**edited to add sample data:**

I need the data in [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xsdb.png) and not [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYDk9.png) were more than one row with country-place shows.

If I add one more case without an aggregation bigquery will show this: **select list expression references which is neither grouped nor aggregated**

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link. Use text for what can be given via text. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12464037/3404097) etc etc This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to search reasonably. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) PS When you do edit a post to focus, don't invalidate reasonable posted answers. PS [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you may need to take here is to split up the aggregations and do a few calculations for the records where `Category = 'cat9'` and non-null country values.

We'll compute the `COUNT()` of those records, grouped by country, place, and label_date like your first query, as well as the `SUM(value)`. Then we'll place your original first query in another aggregated CTE, then we'll select and join them together at the end, along with adding the conditional logic for calculating `s_u`.

```
WITH Cat9s AS
(
    SELECT 
        country
        , place
        , label_date
        , COUNT(*) AS TotalCat9s
        , SUM(IFNULL(value,0)) AS Cat9Sum
    FROM `my_database` 
    WHERE Category = 'cat9' 
    AND country IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY country
        , place
        , label_date
)
,Aggregations AS
(
    SELECT
      country,
      place,
      label_date,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'cat1' THEN Value
        ELSE
        0
      END
        ) AS t_s,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'cat2' THEN Value
        ELSE
        0
      END
        ) AS non_ps,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'cat3' THEN Value
        ELSE
        0
      END
        ) AS f_h,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'cat4' THEN Value
        ELSE
        0
      END) AS f_s,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'cat5' THEN Value
        ELSE
        0
      END) AS o_hp,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'cat6' THEN Value
        ELSE
        0
      END) AS o_hps,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'cat7' THEN Value
        ELSE
        0
      END) AS a_s,
      SUM(CASE
          WHEN Category = 'cat8' THEN Value
        ELSE
        0
      END) AS u_s
    FROM
      `my_database`
    where country is not null 
    GROUP by country, place, label_date
)
SELECT 
    a.country
    ,a.place
    ,a.label_date
    ,a.t_s
    ,a.non_ps
    ,a.f_h
    ,a.f_s
    ,a.o_hp
    ,a.o_hps
    ,a.a_s
    ,a.u_s
    ,CASE WHEN c.Cat9Sum = 0 THEN 1 
            WHEN c.Cat9Sum <> 0 THEN c.Cat9Sum / c.TotalCat9s
        ELSE NULL END AS s_u
FROM Aggregations a
LEFT JOIN Cat9s c ON a.country = c.country 
        AND a.place = c.place
        AND a.label_date = c.label_date
```

Comment: @learner_one If you add some of your sample data, particularly the data that results in the duplicates, I can help you further refine the query.